# Error Comparing Strings in If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors, user-input

I have a variable called "name" stored in another class in the working folder. I want to compare it to a user-input from a JOptionPane. The code I have is this:

```
String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the value?");
if(name.equals(userInput)){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are correct.");}
```

When I compile the program, it throws up the error that it cannot find symbol "name". Do I have to call the variable some other way in order to compare it to the user-input or am I totally wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say in working folder you have following two class:

```
class IHaveNameVariable
{
    String name;
}

class IAccessNameVariable
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        // Uncomment the code below
        // and it will compile.

        // IHaveNameVariable aRef = new IHaveNameVariable();

        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the value?");
        if(/*aRef.*/name.equals(userInput))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are correct.");
        }
    }
}
```

So, that's how you access a field of another class. if the field is `static`, no need to create object using `new`; simply use the class name.

Answer (score 1):

If `name` is a member of a different object, then you will need to specify which object.

```
thingWithAName.name.equals(userInput)
```

Comment: Preferred style is to use an "accessor" method instead of directly grabbing the name.  e.g.  `if (thingWithAName.getName().equals(userInput)) // do something here`